# Student is allowed to request one ticket per 6 months

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a small project says the student is allowed to request one ticket each 6 months here are the codes I wrote and I will link the issue I'm facing.

```
using (var Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = root\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =Log-In; Integrated Security = True"))
        {
            Con.Open();
            var table = "INSERT INTO  Student(username,DepartureCiry,ArrivalCity,DateOfDeparture,DateOfReturn)VALUES(@username,@DepartureCiry,@ArrivalCity,@DateOfDeparture,@DateOfReturn)";

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(table, Con))
                {
                var newDep = "Select DateOfDeparture from Student where username=@username";
                var departValue = new SqlCommand(newDep, Con);
                departValue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                var dataFromDatabase = Convert.ToDateTime(departValue.ExecuteScalar());
                var newStudent = Convert.ToDateTime(date_time_picker.Text);
                var diff = (newStudent - dataFromDatabase);
                MessageBox.Show(diff.ToString());
                if (diff.TotalDays < 180)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("you exceed you're booking for the last 6 monthes");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("request has been sent suckssfully");
                }

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartureCiry", fromtxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArrivalCity", Totxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfDeparture", date_time_picker.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfReturn", date_time_picker1.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data inserted suckssfully");
            }
```

The error:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible

Comment: Side note: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: So what is your question? Why hasn't what you've tried not worked?

Comment: @Larnu no it's not working see the error below the code please

Comment: `"suckssfully"` yep I agree

Comment: There are a couple of conversions taking place in that block of code, have you set breakpoints and stepped through with the debugger? Can you tell us which line is causing the error?

Comment: Why do you use *int diffrance = Convert.ToInt32(diff);* to calculate number of days in *diff*? I think it is impossible to convert *TimeSpan* to *int*. Try to change this line to the next: *int diffrance = diff.TotalDays;*.

Comment: @NikP int diffrance = Convert.ToInt32(diff); this one

Comment: @Keith has it below.

Comment: Guys i'm i doing something really dumb in here ? the problem now solved how ever the system still sending the request to the database anyway ..!! i will update the code so you can see where is my mistake exactly cus i couldn't figure it out

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you have to have "suckssfully" you know what i mean

Comment: So what is the problem now? The problem is that *insert into Student* performed regardless of the value in *diff.TotalDays*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you really should tell us, I'm going to guess that the exception is occurring on this line:

```
int diffrance = Convert.ToInt32(diff);
```

You should take out that line completely, and replace your `if` statement with:

```
if (diff.TotalDays > 180)
```